# Why is the PowerShell console queuing extra asterisk key presses in my commands?

Tags: powershell

When I perform a long-running operation in a normal PowerShell console (this is not the command, but it works and simulates the behavior).

```
PS> Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
```

And I start typing my next command, say `ls **/project.json`... when the previous command returns and my key presses are written to the screen, the number of asterisks (`*`) I see are always one more than I typed. It doesn't seem to matter if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
PS> ls ***/project.json
```

This doesn't seem to happen with any other alphanumeric key. It can happen with mixed asterisks and other alphanumeric keys. But, it doesn't seem to happen if the asterisk is before a period (`.`).

```
PS> ls ***/*.json
```

Any idea what's happening?

---

Environment:

- Windows 10 Pro v1703 OS Build 15063.413
- Windows PowerShell v5.1.15063.413 (normal console)

Comment: I can't repro this on Windows 7.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063] PSVersion 5.1.15063.413

Comment: Able to reproduce on Win10 v1703, PS 5.1.

Comment: Happening with other characters too. I typed `ls &&/project.json` and received `ls &&&/project.json`. I also tried `ls &&project.json` and got `ls &&&project.json` - the `/` doesn't have an influence.

Comment: Only happening when shift is held.  Eg if `{shift-down}, &, &, {shift-up}`, the result is `&&&`. If `{shift-down}, &, {shift-up}, {shift-down}, &, {shift-up}`, the result is `&&`.

Comment: On my system it happens in the PowerShell console, but not in ConEmu. It also doesn't happen in the ISE because it doesn't buffer any characters at all.